# Prove that a function is continuous in $R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that $f$ is continuous at $(0,y_0)$ where $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$
 \begin{cases} 
      (1+xy)^{1/x} & x\neq 0 \\
      e^y &  x=0 \\
   \end{cases}
$$

I'm not really sure how to find the $\delta$ to do a proper epsilon-delta proof, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you deal with some of the $y_0$ ?

Answer (score -1):

Polar coordinates:

$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos t\\y_0=r_0\sin t_0\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies\left(1+rr_0\cos t\sin t_0\right)^{\frac1{r\cos t}}=e^{\frac1{r\cos t}\log\left(1+rr_0\cos t\sin t_0\right)}$$

Now, applying l'Hospital's rule:

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\log\left(1+rr_0\cos t\sin t_0\right)}{r\cos t}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\frac{r_0\cos t\sin t_0}{1+rr_0\cos t\sin t_0}}{\cos t}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r_0\cos t\sin t_0}{\cos t(1+rr_0\cos t\sin t_0)}=r_0\sin t_0$$

So the limit above equals

$$e^{r_0\sin t_0}=e^{y_0}$$